# how do I duplicate LightSwitch DB structure in a second LightSwitch application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

Suppose I have two MS LightSwitch projects. I really like my table layout in one project and want to copy it to the other project. How is this done? What files have the table and key definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to publish the application, then use a copy of the published database as an attached data source in the new project.

The defintions that you ask about are stored in an lsml file (a LightSwitch-specific XML file), *ApplicationDefinition.lsml* for LS 2011, & *Common.lsml* for LS 2012. But be VERY careful if you try to edit this file in any project, it only takes ONE mistake for the whole application to no longer load.

Comment: It appears to be more complicated than a single file. My source project (LS 2012 Silverlight) project has three files: Service.lsml, Common.lsml, and Client.lsml. My target project (LS 2012 HTML5 p2) lacks Common.lsml but has the other two. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: As yes, but you didn't mention that you were using the latest preview of the HTML Client. As you've discovered, this preview changes the current architecture of a LightSwitch 2012 project. The Common.lsml file has now been removed, leaving Client.lsml & Server.lsml. Your definitions will therefore be found in Server.lsml now. Same warning applies as before. Backup first, & be cery careful with any changes to any lsml file.

Answer (score 0):

[WARNING: NEVER DO THE FOLLOWING! IT MESSES UP YOUR PROJECT IN VISUAL STUDIO]

What I did in LS 2013 was to create tables with the same name in the new project, so they are already "known" to your project settings. Then I went to `[project folder]\[project name]\[project name]\[project name].server\DataSources\ApplicationData` of the project I wanted the tables from. I copied the respective files (including script files, if you did data validation, which I also created in the new project with dummy entries) and then overwrote the files with the same name in the respective ApplicationData folder of the new project, which I had created.

When I loaded the project again, Lightswitch showed the new tables in my old project.

Comment: Okay, actually it seems like a bad idea. Lightswitch is not very happy with my copied table and keeps complaining about all kinds of stuff. It seems like messing with the generated structure is not a good idea